# Given two strings s1 and s2, remove all the characters from s1 which is present in s2. is it possible to solve in Angular?

Tags: angular

Want to execute below operation in angular but it's not working. Do any 1 have idea how to solve in Angular .?

output1 should contain all the characters which are present in str1 but NOT present in str2.

output2 should contain all the characters which are present in str2 but NOT present in str1.

Comment: Can you include your current JavaScript code?

Comment: Hi, Not in Angular, try to do this plain Javascript. its very easy to do, use the array functions in JS.

Comment: Thnx @SulabhAgarwal : but in javascript also not able to print .

Answer (score 1):

Split first and second string to form an array and convert them to lowercase letters.

```
var stringOneArray = stringOne.split('').map(a=>a.toLowerCase());
var stringTwoArray = stringTwo.split('').map(a=>a.toLowerCase());
```

All the characters which are present in str1 but NOT present in str2 will be
`stringOneArray.filter(a=>!stringTwoArray.includes(a.toLowerCase()))`

All the characters which are present in str2 but NOT present in str1 will be
`stringTwoArray.filter(a=>!stringOneArray.includes(a.toLowerCase()))`

Comment: Thank you so much @Ameerudheen.k but why I will convert this to lowercase. I just want to print which is not present. e.g  var str1="ABC" var str2 ="BC" and my o/p will be "A"

Comment: if lowercase not needed you can remove that map function and lowercase conversion inside include function

Answer (score 0):

Method for Angular

```
onlyCaracters(): Array<string> (stringOne: string, stringTwo: string) {
 return stringOne.split('').map(a => a.toLowerCase()).filter(a => 
 !stringTwo.split('').map(a=>a.toLowerCase()).includes(a.toLowerCase()))
}
```